# The most Pythonic way to create an object with user inputs

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, instantiation

I was wondering what is the most Pythonic way to create an object whose parameters come from user inputs. Consider the example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.x= a
        self.y= b
        self.z= c
```

Should I have functions elsewhere (in another module?) that asks the user to input values for a, b, c? Alternatively, should I set x, y, z to None and then have helper functions called from the **init** function that prompt the user to set the values for the parameters? What is the most Pythonic way to accomplish this? I've been working with Python for a few years but am (finally) starting prioritize style and code aesthetics.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap it up with this statement

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.x= a
        self.y= b
        self.z= c
       
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = input("Enter a: ")
    b = input("Enter b: ")
    c = input("Enter c: ")
    some_class = SomeClass( a , b, c )
```

Comment: This is good. Thank you. If I wanted to ensure that (for example) "a" can be cast as an integer, however, is the simplest way with a try-except statement around int(input("Enter a: "))? My program has about 10 user inputs, and I'd like to avoid 10 try-catch blocks if possible, as I prefer short modules.

Comment: You can create an is_valid function that test the number at each iteration and save valid input in a list...you can then construct the object with the list

Comment: I really like this approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the most pythonic way to do is using `collections.namedtuple`

```
import collections

a = input("Enter a: ")
b = input("Enter b: ")
c = input("Enter c: ")

obj = collections.namedtuple('Class', [a, b, c])

# Set value to each parameter
obj.a = 10
obj.b = 'Ghanteyyy'
obj.c = True
```

Answer (score 1):

More than the pythonic way of coding your are asking general principles of coding. Generally, you will never have only one class in your program unless you are using python for scripting where you have only one source (.py) file. You also have user-input in your program. You should always keep data and UI separate. So separate class for data and separate for UI. UI class can also validate input before you create data objects using the input.

Comment: I currently have about 15 modules in my program. Some are for computations. Others are for fetching data. Others still are for displaying data. This class is meant to bring it all together -- with some user inputs. It sounds like the right way is to have on module just for getting inputs -- and another module that contains the Class itself. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> There are cases when we need to get user input in a python program then use it during the initialization of a class. For example, if we have a class ‘person’ that has two attributes first name and last name.

```
class Person:
     """
     A representation of a person 
     Attributes:
         Firstname(string)
         Lastname(String)
     """
     def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
         self.firstname = first_name
         self.lastname = last_name 
     def show_full_name(self):
         return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

> To create a person object using this class, we could supply arguments directly without requiring user input. See below.

```
#instance by supplying arguments
person1 = Person('John', 'Doe')
person1.show_full_name()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response -- but that doesn't quite answer my question. I'm building an interactive tool, where the end-user will enter the values he wants through an input function upon running the program (my audience isn't programmers, and I lack GUI programming skills). The question is whether these should be put outside the class, with the inputs then passed individually to the Class __init__ function, or if there should be helper functions inside the Class that ask for the end-user's values. I hope that clarifies things.